# Python word scramble game. How to loop with an incorrect response?

Tags: python, list, while-loop

Hi I am trying to create a simple word scramble game using a list of scrambled words and their answers. However, I want users to be able to try again if they get a word wrong. My current code works great, except I can't figure out how to alter it to allow users to try again at their given word.

Here's my code:

```
def load_words(filename):
#load file containing scrambled word and answer.
#scrambled word and answer are sparated by :
scrambled_list = []
answer_list = []
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        (s,a) = line.strip().split(":")
        scrambled_list+=[s]
        answer_list+=[a]
return (scrambled_list, answer_list)
def random_word(list):
    import random  
    random_word = random.choice(list)
    return random_word
def main():  
    display_banner()  
    (scrambled_list, answer_list) = load_words('halloween.txt')
    import random
    #loop starts here
    another_game = "Y"
    while another_game == "Y":
        print("Scrambled word is: ", random_word(scrambled_list))
        guess=input("What is the word? ")
        if guess in answer_list:
            print("You got it!")
            another_game = input("Another game? (Y/N): ")            
        else:
            print("Wrong answer. Try again!")       
main()
```

Comment: Couple of points: 1) you shouldn't import modules inside functions. Import all modules before any function definitions. 2) your indentations are a bit haphazard. 3) What error are you getting, and what is a sample use/output?

Comment: 4) your logic is flawed. ``if guess in answer_list:`` will accept **any** word as the correct one from the loaded list, not just the scrambled one.

Comment: `while True:` when combined with `if <condition>: break` and possibly `if <condition>: continue` is a very powerful tool at your disposal that might be worth looking into.